# Reaction pathway - Extra molecule used in one step only?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I am currently building a reaction mechanism through Gaussian calculations. I successfully found each TS and intermediates through the different jobs (opt, freq, irc) for my 3-step mechanism from reactants to my products.

However, I was questioning myself about one step in particular which could involve one extra molecule. Here's a scheme of my system:

$$\ce{A + B -> C <=> D -> E}$$

Where A and B are in same equivalence experimentally.

All steps are characterized by stable intermediates and reasonable energy barriers confirming experimental data, except one step. The step from *C* to *D* is a simple tautomerism from enol to ketone. However, this proton exchange needs to be driven by a proton acceptor like *B* to have a energy barrier that is closer to the reality. Then, for my system, an extra molecule *B* could be implied in the mechanism only from this *C* to *D* step.

Practically, you perform optimization of your TS and complex of products and reactants involving all molecules for the reaction step. However, I was wondering if I can draw a reaction pathway from *A* and *B* to *E* without the extra molecule *B* and involving it only for the step where it is required (as a sort of catalyst). Let's make it more clear:

1. I take the step *A* and *B* to *C* as already calculated
2. I perform *C* to *D* with an extra molecule *B* acting as proton acceptor for that step
3. I take the step from *D* to *E*

In this way, the extra *B* is used only in the second step of the mechanism and I can get from there the relative energies. However, in that case, how can I draw the mechanism plot with all relative energies ? *C* or *C + B* have totally different energies. Am I forced to re optimize all my system with an extra *B* molecule ?

Comment: Are these A, B, C, D and E substances corresponding to real molecules ? Or are they here simply for the fun of writing kinetics formula ? Is it possible to imagine that for example$\ce{A = C2HR, B = H2O, C = RCHCHOH, D = RCH2-CHO}$ and $\ce{E}$ is something else ? So, why thinking that a second B is necessary ?

Comment: It is as example instead of providing a real system. The other B would act as a sort of catalyst for only one step of the mechanism and would not be involved in the other steps (except in the first one but as reactant).